# Why do I get a cube when I try the Fracture Modifier on a sphere?

Tags: modifiers

Heyhey,
if I try to fracture a cube, everything works well but if I try the same with a sphere I just get another fractured cube. Why is that? 
Here is the result when I try to fracture a sphere [image]

If you would have any idea of how to fix that I would be very glad.
My aim was to create something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noqxBQ2TZaU&list=PLI0-9khDuTlgFvhBndWQgJS18fq5TXXQy&index=16
Best regards
Fabrice

Comment: That is most likely a bug in the script, nothing you can do to fix it, other than report a bug to the author

Comment: What?! I can do nothing to fix it? How do I report the bug to the autor? Can I hope for a patch to fix this bug soon? I already isntalled the latest version of Blender.

Comment: Unless you know how to code and fix bugs I don't think there is much you can do about that error. Contact the author at the thread, maybe? https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343637-Custom-Build-Blender-Fracture-Modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you already downloaded the Fracture Modifier Build. Here is a general introduction tutorial for it (its from 2014 but the basic principles work still in the same way.)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E0Nn_a6wCs

And the documentation site:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Scorpion81/Fracture_Documentation

Or you could just try to run the cell-fracture script in object mode. You tried to run it in edit mode where it obviously is not supposed to run and errors out then. By the way, the cell fracture script is completely independent of the Fracture Modifier.

When you use the Fracture Modifier (FM), you get a faster version of cell fracture with a lot more customization options. The smashing spheres could be 2 Objects, with a FM each. Just hit execute Fracture on both and Alt-A and the simulation starts (the spheres will fall down). Then you can animate the spheres, set them to Animated and Triggered, and make each sphere a Trigger, too. Optionally you could also use constraints within the FM. Then, when the spheres collide, they will break apart as well.

Comment: Oh my god. This is it!! I made the msitake by fracting it in the edit mode. I need to do it in the object mode. I tryed taht before but I didn't noticed that he creates the fractions on Layer 2. Thank you much @scorpion81!

Comment: @Frece don't just thank in the comments, upvte the question if it helped you. If it solved your problem consider upvoting it.